# Basic integer calculator

Tags: integer, calculator

Writing a basic calculator. Takes integers and a type of operation, and performs the operation on the integers. I just started learning Python, coming over with a decent amount of MATLAB experience. Can't seem to get past the first "if" statement...

```
def calculator (num1, num2, operation):
    '''
    Parameters:
    -----------
    num1 : (float)
    num2 : (float)
    operation : (str)
        Can take the following values:
        multiplication, addition, subtraction, division

    Returns:
    --------
    answer : (float)
        The result of the indication operation performed on the two numbers

    Notes:  
    ------
    1. Subtraction and division are not distributive operations. This progam assumes that the user wants 
       the first number divided/subtracted by the second number
    2. As you may know any number divided by zero will result in an error. When this occurs, the program 
       raise a ValueError"
    '''

    # start writing your code below

    num1 = int(input('ENTER FIRST NUMBER'))
    num2 = int(input('ENTER SECOND NUMBER'))

    operation = input('input type of operation')

    if operation == 'multiplication'
        answer = num1 * num2
        else if operation == "addition"
        answer = num1 + num2
        else if operation == "subtraction"
        answer = num1 - num2
        else operation == "division"
        answer = num1 / num2

    return answer
```

Just getting a syntax error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Any time you have a question about a “syntax error” [please tell us what the error is](https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabflavor/article/please_please_please/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  It's important to pay strict attention to tabs and syntax when writing Python.  I recommend PyCharm by JetBrains for your IDE.  They write the best IDEs on the market, hands down.

```
__author__ = 'Michael'


class NoSuchOperationError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, code):
        self.code = code

    def __str__(self):
        return repr(self.code)



def calculator(num1, num2, operation):
    """
    Parameters:
    -----------
    num1 : (float)
    num2 : (float)
    operation : (str)
        Can take the following values:
        multiplication, addition, subtraction, division

    Returns:
    --------
    answer : (float)
        The result of the indication operation performed on the two numbers

    Notes:
    ------
    1. Subtraction and division are not distributive operations. This progam assumes that the user wants
       the first number divided/subtracted by the second number
    2. As you may know any number divided by zero will result in an error. When this occurs, the program
       raise a ValueError"
    """

    if operation == '*':
        answer = num1 * num2
    elif operation == "+":
        answer = num1 + num2
    elif operation == "-":
        answer = num1 - num2
    elif operation == "/":
        answer = num1 / num2
    else:
        raise NoSuchOperationError(operation)
    return answer


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # start writing your code below

    num1 = int(input('1st argument: '))
    num2 = int(input('2nd argument: '))

    operation = input('operation (+,-,*, or /): ')
    print(calculator(num1, num2, operation))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several different issues here:

1. Whitespace is significant in Python.  The same level of code must have the same indentation.  So `if` and its corresponding `else` must have the same level of indentation.  All the  lines in the `if` block must have the same level of indentation.
2. A line containing things like `if` tests and `for` loops must end in a `:`.  So `if blah:`, `else:`, `for x in blah:`.
3. You can't do `else if blah`.  You can even do `else: if blah:`, since nothing except comments can be after the `:`.  You should use `elif blah:`, which is the equivalent of MATLAB's `elseif`.
4. There is no `if` at all in the `division` case.